# Laravel PayTM checksum generation in controller

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, checksum, paytm

i am developing a multi shop Laravel application, where user can choose products from the various shops listed with application, user can select product from single store at a time, i want to configure PayTM payment gateway for every shops listed with application, so payment directly credited in the shop account, from where customer is ordering.

i have created a payment method table with below fields:

```
shop_id,
api_key <-- unique key for each shop listed,
PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY,
PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID,
```

How can i generate checksum for requests for payment for different stores?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer paytm checksum sdk for PHP.

`composer require paytm/paytmchecksum`